# How to merge from branch to branch in svn?

Tags: svn, merge, branch

We have a fairly typical SVN repository setup, with `^/trunk` holding the current stable version of our software, and development/bugfixes going on in feature branches located under `^/branches/<feature>`. Branches are kept in sync with trunk, and once a branch is feature-complete, it has to pass a series of tests before it is reintegrated into `^/trunk`.

Sometimes, however, I'm finished with a feature in `^/branches/A` and would like to work on another feature in `^/branches/B` (**that depends on `A`**), in its own branch, before branch `^/branches/A` can be reintegrated into `^/trunk`. What is the best practice for getting features from one branch in another, without "breaking" the history more than necessary?

Just to clarify what I mean with "break": My aim is that when `^/branches/A` is finally reintegrated into `^/trunk`, and I do a merge from `trunk` to `^/branches/B`, it should not produce any conflicts and the "blame" of the work should still be contributed correctly when I finally reintegrate `^/branches/B` into `trunk` as well.

P.S.: This should work with svn <= 1.7, since we cannot switch to 1.8 yet.

**Update**

Since I do not want to create a branch from a branch (`A` should be reintegrate-able without having to wait for `B`), I tried the following:

```
svn cp http://repo/trunk http://repo/branches/A
<... do some changes to A, commit to A>
svn cp http://repo/trunk http://repo/branches/B
svn co http://repo/branches/B
cd B
svn merge ^/branches/A
```

However, in that case I get a lot of merge conflicts even though I have not changed anything in `trunk` or `branches/B` since the creation of `branches/A`. Any explanation for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the answer that works for me is the following: use svn >= 1.8.

Although it was asked specifically in the question that svn 1.8 cannot be used, the simplest answer is still to use it anyways - but just for the merge operation and nothing else.

This works because all that needs to be done is checking out a copy of the branch to merge to, doing the merge, and committing it with a svn 1.8+ client. Afterwards, the working copy can be deleted and svn 1.7 can be used as before for the normal workflow.

Answer (score 0):

If Feature B is not dependent on Feature A to function, then I would suggest that you don't bother merging them together at all. They are independent features, so you should treat them independently throughout their life, including the merge back to trunk. In the worst case, Feature B will get the Feature A changes right after Feature A merges to trunk.

If your goal is simply testing all your features in one build, what I do often in this situation is to create a third "integration" branch from trunk. I then merge changes from both feature branches to this "integration" branch, but only for testing purposes. Once the features are fully developed, I can merge each back to trunk independently and discard my integration branch. If I'm feeling especially paranoid I can compare trunk to my integration branch to make sure the resulting final merge matched what I tested with.

If Feature B DOES depend on Feature A to function, then I'd be inclined to start the Feature B branch off the Feature A branch instead of creating it from trunk. However, that's not strictly necessary. You should be able to merge Feature A into Feature B, and since the SAME change happened on each branch, any merge tool worth anything will not have a problem with that (unless you make further changes to that line, I suppose). And `svn blame` will only note a change in a line if the diff of that revision shows a change in that line. If your merge leaves a line as it was before the merge, blame will not change the revision shown for that line.

Comment: I've updated my question to be a little more specific. Yes, `B` does depend on `A`, and I want to be able to reintegrate `A` without having to wait for `B` to finished as well, so branch-of-a-branch is not an option for me.